# Temporary Table within Dynamic SQL (SQL-Server)

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a stored procedure in MSSQL and within this stored procedure I am declaring a temporary table (let's call this table `@TempTable`) and inserting some stuff in it. So far, so good. But at a later point in this procedure, I need to use dynamic sql, because a few parameters of the procedure are column names of an existing table.
And within this dynamic sql statement I need to compare some values of the real table and the `@TempTable`

So the statement looks like

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500)

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT A.ColumnA FROM RealTable A, ' + @TempTable + ' B 
WHERE A.' + @ColumnParameter + ' = B.ColumnA'

EXEC (@SQLString)
```

But in this case, SQL thinks that `@TempTable` is a scalar variable, which needs to be declared. I also tried it this way:

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500)

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT A.ColumnA FROM RealTable A, @TempTable B 
WHERE A.' + @ColumnParameter + ' = B.ColumnA'

EXEC (@SQLString)
```

But, of course in this case, the table variable @TempTable needs to be declared, because it does not know, that this is a table, I declared previously (outside this statement). So, my question is, how do I use a temporary table within a dynamic sql correctly?

Comment: You could simply declare the table as an actual table in the database (temporarily), then drop it once its finished with

Comment: What version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Executing the dynamic SQL is done in a scope where the table variable is not available so you will not be able to do it like this. Using a real temporary table instead of a table variable could solve your issue as this table is actually stored in your temp database.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `@TempTable` inseide dynamic query

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500)

SET @SQLString = N'DECLARE @TempTable AS TABLE(
    Id INT,
    ColumnA VARCHAR(50)
)
SELECT 
    A.ColumnA 
FROM RealTable A
INNER JOIN @TempTable B ON A.' + @ColumnParameter + ' = B.ColumnA'

EXEC (@SQLString)
```

Comment: I thought about that too, but that would mean, that I will also need to put the part, where I am inserting some values in this temp table, also in the dynamic sql (or am I wrong with that?) and I would like to avoid that and keep the dynamic sql as short and simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use temporary table:

```
USE tempdb
IF OBJECT_ID(N'#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp

USE YourDB

SELECT SomeColumns
INTO #temp
FROM SomeTables

DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500)


SET @SQLString = N'
SELECT A.ColumnA 
FROM RealTable A
INNER JOIN #temp B 
    ON A.' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnParameter) + ' = B.ColumnA'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString
```

It is a sample of how you can overpass the limitations of the table variables.

Few notes:

- Use `sp_executesql`
- Use `QUOTENAME` for column/table names you pass in dynamic query.